# 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')' exception on the dataFridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

private void guna2DataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString);
        if (e.ColumnIndex != 0 && e.ColumnIndex != guna2DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1 && e.ColumnIndex != guna2DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 2)
        {
            string item = productIds[e.ColumnIndex - 1];
            string color = colors[e.ColumnIndex - 1];
            string itemOld = productIds[e.ColumnIndex - 1];
            string colorOld = colors[e.ColumnIndex - 1];
            int targetColumnIndex = e.ColumnIndex;
            DialogResult result = Changecolumn(ref item, ref color, 300, 200);
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in guna2DataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    if (row.Cells[0].ReadOnly)
                    {
                        // Check if the target column index is valid
                        if (row.Cells[targetColumnIndex].Value != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells[targetColumnIndex].Value.ToString()))
                        {
                            string car_number = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                            string query = $"update GKloading set ProductID = @item, Color = @color where Kiln_Car_number = @KilnCarNumber and ProductID = @Item0 and Color = @Color0 AND DateandTime = (SELECT MAX(DateandTime) FROM GKloading WHERE kiln_car_number = @KilnCarNumber)";
                            SqlCommand cmd0 = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                            cmd0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item", item);
                            cmd0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@color", color);
                            cmd0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KilnCarNumber", car_number);
                            cmd0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item0", itemOld);
                            cmd0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Color0", colorOld);

                            try
                            {
                                con.Open();
                                int rowsAffected = cmd0.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {}
                            con.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                string headerText = $"{item} {color}";
                productIds.RemoveAt(targetColumnIndex - 1);
                colors.RemoveAt(targetColumnIndex - 1);
                productIds.Insert(targetColumnIndex - 1, item);
                colors.Insert(targetColumnIndex - 1, color);
                guna2DataGridView1.Columns[targetColumnIndex].HeaderText = headerText;
                                                
            }
```

I was trying to change the headerText of a column,
guna2DataGridView1.Columns[targetColumnIndex].HeaderText = headerText; // error code

exception : System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')'

Comment: So what was the actual index you used and what was the valid range of indexes for the collection? This is the sort of information that you need to look for for yourself in an effort to address the issue before posting a question. If you still need help, then you provide that diagnostic information to us.